How can I fix this edge distortion problem on a hollow cylinder?
This may be a silly question but I'm just starting out, I am just playing around with shapes as I want to make some 3d art. To cut to the chase I want to cut a cross section of a cylinder similar to when you cut a carrot or chive on an angle.
The problem I encounter is after I create the cylinder and cut it using the bisect tool or translate the cylinders edge I get an odd distortion instead of a clean flat cut. I'm sure I'm missing something but I'd just like to know what.
In addition, I made the cylinder by creating a curve from an edge> object data properties>  increasing its depth in the geometry/bevel tab> making it a mesh> solidifying it.
A few screenshots below demonstrates what I mean and I've pulled a random photo off the internet showing what edge I'd prefer.
Thank you and any help will be greatly appreciated. :)




One way to do this would be to use a mesh cylinder that you have Ctrl->A applied scale and rotation to:

Remove the end faces and use a solidify modifier to give it the wall thickness wanted and then apply the modifier:

Add a plane and rotate it to the angle wanted and Ctrl->A apply rotation. Then move the plane to where you want to cut the angle, select the cylinder and use a boolean modifier to cut the end:

Result after applying the boolean modifier:


I thought there would be a good simple explanation to this. Thank you very much for your help!
